# How to fix positional associations Error (10437)

Tags: vhdl

What I want to do is to take some bits of an std_logic_vector, then sign-extend them and afterwards assert them to another std_logic_vector

Lets say, I have the following

```
 A : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 B : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
```

I want to do this:

```
A <= 000...0 & B(6 downto 0)
where "000...0" = 25 zeros
```

*My Code is the following:*

```
PC     : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
PC_ADD : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

--- 
--- Inside the architecture i do this

PC_ADD <= (6 DOWNTO 0 => PC(8 DOWNTO 2), (OTHERS => '0'));
```

I get the following error:

> Error (10437): VHDL Association List error at XXXXX.vhd: positional
>   associations must be listed before named associations

Comment: You need to enable VHDL-2008 support. The parenthesis around others is wrong.

Comment: Besides using --2008 remove the parentheses from around the second named association.  Provide a [mcve]. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General, para 3 (in part) "An element association is said to be *named* if the elements are specified explicitly by choices; otherwise, it is said to be *positional*."